# Remove the square brackets from json response

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a json response as `[120.0]`, and I want to show the value in a textview. I'm getting the value from json response as shown below,

```
price.add(object.getString("Price"));
```

and then displaying it in textview as shown below,

```
TextView priceTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
priceTV .setText("( + $ " + price + " ) ");
```

When I done this it shows me the output as,

```
( $ [120.0] )
```

My problem is I want to remove the square brackets which is around 120.0. 
then i can get a output like,

```
( $ 120.0 )
```

How can I achieve it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

```
priceTV.setText("( + $ " + price.get(0) + " ) ");
```

Comment: I got this error message The method replace(char, char) is undefined for the type List<String>

Comment: I want to show this in my onCreat and I'm getting java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255). I'm trying to work it out and update you

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `replaceAll` to remove []

**EXAMPLE**

```
//get your String
String pricestring = object.getString("Price");
//remove []
pricestring = pricestring.replaceAll("[", "");
pricestring  = pricestring.replaceAll("]", "");
//add to array
price.add(pricestring);
```